# Reading content from google doc using JavaScript and displaying on web page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am new to apps script and google drive / docs apis. My requirement is that I am authoring my blog / content using google doc. Once authored I want to fetch these docs and display on my web page as html.

I am looking for JavaScript library which can fetch google docs as html and I can then display fetched content in a  on html page.

Comment: Why don't you just Publish to web and then you can embed them in your blog.

Comment: I would like to extend it where multiple users can co-author and preview the content / page. I would publish to web once the content if final. So, is there is a way to fetch content using JavaScript and display it on page in preview mode?

Comment: Try [URLFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/)